# If the vectors (2, 3, 4) and (10, y, z) are perpendicular, how must $y$ and $z$ be related?

Tags: vectors

I'm trying to solve this question by using the dot product property for vectors that are perpendicular where if you multiply the vectors, they should equal $0$. I've tried the following:

- $ 20 + 3y + 4z = 0$
- $3y + 4z = -20$

I'm unsure how to find a $y$ or $z$ value that makes $(10, y, z)$ perpendicular to $(2, 3, 4)$ from here.

Comment: It seems youi have used dot product properly, and indeed you have found a relation between $y$ and $z$, that is a plane.

Comment: You’re pretty much done.  *Any* $y, z$ that satisfy the relation you found will work.  Do you see why?  (And I have no idea why this question was downvoted.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're basically done. For **any** pair $(y, z)$ that satisfies the linear relation $3y + 4z = -20$, the vector $(10, y, z)$ is perpendicular to $(2, 3, 4)$. For example $(y, z) = (-4, -2)$ works and you can check that $(10, -4, -2)$ works. Here's a picture of the linear relation:

[image: Linear relation with integer points.]

I've indicated some points with integer coordinates, but **any** points on the line work. And each one corresponds to a vector perpendicular to $(2, 3, 4)$.

There's a whole *line's worth* of solutions because in $3$-dimensional space, there's a whole $2$-d *plane's worth* of vectors perpendicular to a give one. Once we restrict our attention to only those vectors in the plane for which the first coordinate $x=10$, then we get the $1$-d line of solutions. In general$^\dagger$ each equation cuts the dimension of the space of solutions down by $1$. Here we have $2$ equations in a $3$-d space and $3-2=1$.

---

$^\dagger\!$ Lines, planes, and other subspaces can be parallel or otherwise not intersect in this generic fashion, but these are interesting edge cases. This discussion of dimension is only meant to inspire intuition about dimensions, and it *is exactly* what happens in all but those edge cases.

Comment: I don't understand why the textbook is saying that the answer is $y=-4/3$ and $z=-20/3$, I don't understand how these are the answers when they don't work when I plug them into this equation $3y+4z=−20$

Comment: Congratulations! You've found a mistake in your textbook! With $y=-\tfrac43$ the vector $\bigl(10, -\tfrac43, \color{red}{-4}\bigr)$ works. Or with $z=-\tfrac{20}{3}$ the vector $\bigl(10, \color{red}{\tfrac{20}{9}}, -\tfrac{20}{3}\bigr)$ works. Either of $y$ or $z$ determines the other, and it turns out that pair doesn't work.